# How to style html input elements (radio buttons and ckeck-boxes) for print out of Microsoft Forms

Tags: css, printing, developer-tools, ms-forms

I use Microsoft Forms for assessing my students online.
I then need to print out (can't be digital) each single result to correct them and send the back.
However, the radio buttons and check boxes have a very poor contrast, so you can hardly see them on the printed document. Is there any way to change this? I tried using developer tools and was able to style the input fields on screen but not for the print.
Happy for any advice.

Comment: In case anybody cares:
in dev tools simply adding
svg{
  fill: rgb(050, 050, 050) !important;
}
did the job